# oauth2orize sample returns AuthorizationError: not authorized

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth2orize

I've downloaded the [oauth2orize provider code example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize/tree/master/examples/all-grants) and the [sample oauth client](https://github.com/coolaj86/example-oauth2orize-consumer) suggested in the docs and I'm getting the following error:

> 500 AuthorizationError: not authorized at validated
>   (/Users/trevorallred/projects/pics/node-soa/oauth2orize/examples/all-grants/node_modules/oauth2orize/lib/middleware/authorization.js:131:36)
>   at
>   /Users/trevorallred/projects/pics/node-soa/oauth2orize/examples/all-grants/oauth2.js:180:14
>   at Object.exports.findByClientId
>   (/Users/trevorallred/projects/pics/node-soa/oauth2orize/examples/all-grants/db/clients.js:24:10)
>   at exports.authorization.res.render.transactionID
>   (/Users/trevorallred/projects/pics/node-soa/oauth2orize/examples/all-grants/oauth2.js:174:16)
>   at
>   /Users/trevorallred/projects/pics/node-soa/oauth2orize/examples/all-grants/node_modules/oauth2orize/lib/middleware/authorization.js:167:9 at pass
>   (/Users/trevorallred/projects/pics/node-soa/oauth2orize/examples/all-grants/node_modules/oauth2orize/lib/server.js:262:26)
>   at pass
>   (/Users/trevorallred/projects/pics/node-soa/oauth2orize/examples/all-grants/node_modules/oauth2orize/lib/server.js:280:9)
>   at pass
>   (/Users/trevorallred/projects/pics/node-soa/oauth2orize/examples/all-grants/node_modules/oauth2orize/lib/server.js:271:11)
>   at Server._parse
>   (/Users/trevorallred/projects/pics/node-soa/oauth2orize/examples/all-grants/node_modules/oauth2orize/lib/server.js:285:5)
>   at authorization
>   (/Users/trevorallred/projects/pics/node-soa/oauth2orize/examples/all-grants/node_modules/oauth2orize/lib/middleware/authorization.js:118:12)

I'm running the client here: `http://localhost:3002/`
I click the link to "Connect with example-oauth2orize"

It redirects me to the provider: `http://localhost:3000/login`

After logging in with "bob" I'm sent to this error page.

The only modifications I've made are to oauth-config.js in the example client.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
        provider: {
                protocol: "http",
                host: "localhost:3000",
                profileUrl: "/api/userinfo"
        },
        consumer: {
                protocol: "http",
                host: "localhost:3002"
        }
};
```

I tried modifying oauth-consumer-config.js after I saw [this bug report](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize/issues/91) but it didn't seem to change any behavior.

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'Example Consumer App'
, icon: 'http://example.com/icon_64.png'
, clientId: 'trevorclient'
, clientSecret: 'kasdfasdfoq34t134tg109gqerg1gjc'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your **oauth-consumer-config.js** file to this:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'Example Consumer App'
, icon: 'http://localhost:3000/icon_64.png'
, clientId: 'abc123'
, clientSecret: 'ssh-secret'
};
```

The problem is that the `all-grants` example doesn't actually use a DB, but a flat file for illustration purposes. If you navigation to **db/clients.js** in the `all-grants` project, you'll see the clients listed there that are allowed to connect via OAuth.